# When a user clicks the fineuploader button, how can I redirect them instead of showing the file selection dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, fine-uploader

We are using .net and fineuploader.  If the users session has timed out and they click the fineuploader button, we need to be able to redirect them to a login page instead of showing them the file selection dialog.

We have been able to sort-of do it in the "submit" event of fineuploader but the user still sees the file selection dialog before they do our redirect.

```
$("#fine-uploader").fineUploader().on("submit", function (event, id, name) 
{
  if (noSession){
    cancelUploads();
    window.onbeforeunload = function () { return; }
    location.href = "/login";
  }
}
```

I did not see any events that fire before the file selection dialog, unless I missed it (http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/events.html).

Is there a way to do something before the file selection dialog is shown?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you _not_ cancel all user uploads. You run the risk of really annoying your users, since they will not be able to resume any of these uploads.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is *probably* as simple as attaching a click handler to the underlying file input element, preventing the browser's default action on click (which normally shows the file chooser), and then redirect the user to the page of your choice:

```
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')
   .addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      location.href = "/login"
   })
```

Add this event handler when you want to redirect, and remove it when you don't. Or, you can add it after the uploader has been created, and add some logic to the click handler function that only prevents the default action and redirects if the user must re-login.

Warning: I have *not* tested this cross-browser (only Chrome).

Comment: It's funny that this was downvoted, since it's the only correct answer here that actually addresses the question of "how do I prevent the file chooser from appearing?"

Answer (score -1):

you can use prevent default to stop the submit action and run your check. 
Use an else statement to finish the submit if they are logged in.

```html
$("#fine-uploader").fineUploader().on("submit", function (event, id, name) 
{  event.preventDefault();
  if (noSession){
        cancelUploads();
        window.onbeforeunload = function () { return; }
        location.href = "/login";
      }
  else{
        return true;
      }
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: This is for a form submit. Fine Uploader's submit event is related to submission of files to the library.

Comment: It is still an .on("submit", function)

Comment: onSubmit

Called when the item has been selected and is a candidate for uploading.

This does not mean the item is going to be uploaded. Return false to prevent submission to the uploader. A promise can be used if non-blocking work is required. Processing of this item is deferred until the promise is fullfilled. If a promise is returned, a call to failure is the same as returning false.

Comment: event.preventDefault does nothing here. Regardless, none of this will prevent the file chooser from appearing, since the submit event can only be sent _after_ the file chooser has already been dismissed. The question is: "how do I prevent the file chooser from appearing?"

Comment: You can always use .on('click', function(){}) if you need to tie it to a click instead of a submit action, then use $("fine-uploader").trigger('click'); for the logged in user if you need to tie it to the click event.

Comment: No, none of that will work. The question pertains to a file input element inside of the HTML rendered by the library.